# Laravel migration: fields that defined as interger wil be treated as auto increment?

Tags: laravel

Here is my code:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('sysmods', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('mod_id');
            $table->string('mod_name','60');
            $table->string('mod_alias_name','60');
            $table->integer('mod_tb_id','6');// this will become auto increment?
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

when i run the migrate command, it says:
" [PDOException]
 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table def
 inition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key"

Then as i check the sql, I found this:
     (SQL: create table `la_sysmods` (`mod_id` int unsigned not null auto_increm
 ent primary key, `mod_name` varchar(60) not null, `mod_alias_name` varchar(
 60) not null, ***`mod_tb_id` int not null auto_increment primary key***, `created
 _at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default character set utf
 8 collate utf8_unicode_ci)

The field 'mod_tb_id' which marked as integer has become increments. What's the problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The second argument for the integer method is the autoIncrement variable. You need to remove it.

**The Laravel method**

```
public function integer($column, $autoIncrement = false, $unsigned = false)
{
    return $this->addColumn('integer', $column, compact('autoIncrement', 'unsigned'));
}
```

Change this:

```
$table->integer('mod_tb_id','6');// this will become auto increment?
```

To this:

```
$table->integer('mod_tb_id');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace your

```
$table->integer('mod_tb_id','6');// this will become auto increment?
```

with

```
$table->integer('mod_tb_id')->length(6);
```

or

```
$table->integer('mod_tb_id', false, false)->length(6);
```

The second argument for integer() method is the flag for `autoincrement` and the third is for `unsigned`.

Hope it helps